# Nested each closure results in NoSuchMethodError

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm completely stumped as to why this is happening and the stack trace I get isn't really helpful to me. I'm sending a `post` request to one of my controllers in Grails. The action handling the request is as follows:

```
def save() {
    def files = request.getFiles("images")
    def json = JSON.parse(request.getParameter("json"))

    // Redacted
}
```

Looping over  `images` and `json` separately works fine:

```
files.each {
    println it
}

json.each {
    println it
}
```

But nesting them does not:

```
files.each { img ->
    json.each { jsn ->
        println "$img: $jsn"
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is the user uploads X amount of images and a json payload. The json would contain new names for the uploaded files, so I would loop through each file and rename it to the name specified in the json. So I'm trying to achieve something like this (assuming same files and json are of equal sizes):

```
files.each { image ->
    json.names.each { newName ->
        image.renameTo(new File(destination, "$newName.jpg"))
    }
}
```

---

It's strange that it doesn't work as in my `index` action I'm doing that same thing:

```
categories.each { category ->
        images.each { image ->
            // Redacted
        }
    }
```

However the difference here is that `categories` and `images` are both defined as instance variables of the controller:

```
private categories = []
private images = []
```

---

Stack trace:

```
URI: /api/images/save
Class: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Message: null
Caused by: gabriel.ApiController$_save_closure6: method <init (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V not found


    Line | Method
->> 1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoSuchMethodError: gabriel.ApiController$_save_closure6: method <init>(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V not found
->>   91 | save      in ApiController.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Looping over the list of names for each file will attempt to rename each file to every name in the list. I think maybe you want to rename each file to the name _at the same index_ in the json list?

Comment: Also please post the full error.

Comment: @doelleri ah yes! So then I would use `eachWithIndex { }` on the files list and grab the name I want from the json with the same index. I've updated the question to include the stack trace. It errors out right at the first line where the closure would start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `Build -> Rebuild Project` seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
files.each {file,index->
   File img = new File( json[index])
   file.transferTo(img)    
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `eachWithIndex` which does work alone, but when you toss in the `json`, it errors out with `NoSuchMethod` and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: You are correct. But the problem is you are trying to access **renameTo()** method from **request.getFiles("images")**, which is not possible. If you want to rename the file